# BASH: Storing nested command arguments in variables

Tags: bash

This is my first time with real bash scripting, and I'm having quite a trouble with expansions and quoting.

I'm writing a script that tests a ssh connection and some remote mysql commands if given the parameter -t, and uses them on the real remote server if given the parameter -r. I want to store the options of the ssh and mysql commands into variables, so when -r or -t are given, it uses the same routine.

Long story short, the script looks more or less like this:

```
sql="SELECT id FROM user WHERE (email LIKE '%a@b.com' OR email LIKE '%c@d.com');"

case "$1" in
  -t )
      ssh_opts=(localhost -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
      mysql_opts=(-u root --password=password test);;

  -r )
      ssh_opts=("-oCheckHostIP no" "-oCompression yes" "-oProtocol 2" "-oProxyCommand connect -4 -S localhost:9050 $(tor-resolve remoteip localhost:9050) 22" remoteip -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -l httpd)
      mysql_opts=('-h mysqlserver' '-P 3306' '-u user' '--password=password' database) -t );;
esac


read -a ids < <(ssh "${ssh_opts[@]}" \"mysql "${mysql_opts[@]" --disable-column-names -B -e \"$'${sql}'\""\")
csv_ids=$(IFS=,; echo "${ids[*]}")
```

As you might have noticed I am very lost at this point, and I feel that this is getting too complicated. Could anyone share some tips on how to do this properly?

Thank you

Comment: I'm... not surprised you're having trouble with this. Consider using a SSH tunnel instead of running the commands over SSH.

Comment: Yes, or also, drop the idea of making the script so dynamic. After all, if I explicitly write the commands, everything works.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this question has to do with "stor[ing] complex command arguments into functions". It could probably stand to have a better title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing so badly until this part:

```
read -a ids < <(ssh "${ssh_opts[@]}" \"mysql "${mysql_opts[@]" --disable-column-names -B -e \"$'${sql}'\""\")
```

To generate the mysql command, use `printf %q` to quote them, and then use that string which `printf %q` correctly quoted for you:

```
printf -v mysql_opts_str '%q ' "${mysql_opts[@]}"
ssh "${ssh_opts[@]}" "mysql $mysql_opts_str ..."
```

The original form didn't work because `\"foo bar\"` is parsed as two arguments: `"foo`, and `bar"`; the quotes are treated as data, not syntax, when escaped.

---

That said -- bash is usually the Wrong Tool to use for interacting with SQL; it doesn't provide tools for parsing arbitrary table contents (so you end up making assumptions about the results of your queries), nor does it provide tools for passing arbitrary strings as bound variables. (I once wrote a command-line Oracle client with this support, intended for use by shell scripts, but it was never publicly released). You should seriously consider using a tool better suited to the job.

Comment: Thank you! I went for a Ruby script though. It was too tough. I guess Bash is to be kept simple.